# Setting a background picture to 100%

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on the site http://cardinalmma.com/. In the bottom you can see a cage like background image. My client want it to set the background image to the browser window size. Inspite of doing some css tweaks i cannot set the background image to 100% of the browser size.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: I had solved this issue by taking the background div to top just after the body statement where the parent element the body has 100% width so it applies to its child element background also

Answer (score 0):

Remove your background from #background and add it to body like so..

```
body{
background: url(images/19-background.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `background-size` property.

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 body{ background: url("ur image") no-repeat cover ;}
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a nice jQuery plugin  which is able to scale pictures to fullscreen size. Depending in what you want to achieve this could be a solution for you, too.

http://vegas.jaysalvat.com